# Asus ROG Strix Scar 15 G532LV RAM upgrade result in stuttering of apps

Tags: windows, memory, performance, freeze

This week I upgraded my RAM to 32GB with this Kingston pack HX432S20IB2K2/32 on my ROG Strix Scar 15 G532LV . Since this upgrade, a lot of apps are stuttering most of the time(not all of the time and not same apps).

I've already tried to do a memtest and the result was 0 errors. CPU stays on idle at ~8%.

Comment: Did Kingston recommend this module for your machine? Is it returnable?

Comment: I had before these modules, 1 module of the same series from Kingston but with only 8GB and a Samsung module of 8GB, and it's worked fine.

Comment: Yesterday I had a BSOD with the following error dpc_watchdog_violation. Unfortunately, I don't know how to find what caused this BSOD.

Comment: Get a copy of Blue Screen View (Nirsoft.net) and then look in your minidump folder. You may have to enable minidumps  (look in Advanced System Settings, Under the Start-up and Recovery section, click Settings:
Finally, select Small Memory Dump from the debugging drop-down menu, then click OK:.  Restart and at the next BSOD, look at the minidump with Blue Screen View to get the error.

Comment: This is what I get from BlueScreenView [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/11jp940)

Answer (score 1):

Bugcheck 0x133 is a Watch Dog violation and generally represents a driver issue.  The Blue Screen windows is not much more explicit than NT Kernel and System.

I suggest (if you can do this) to update BIOS, Chipset (if there is a Chipset driver), Firmware drivers, Video and power drivers. That may clear the BSOD and possibly fix the stuttering.

[Bugcheck 0x133][1]

> In general this stop code is caused by faulty driver code that under
> certain conditions, does not complete its work within the allotted
> time frame.
>
> If you are not equipped to use the Windows debugger to this problem,
> you should use some basic troubleshooting techniques.
>
> If a driver is identified in the bug check message, to isolate the
> issue, disable the driver. Check with the manufacturer for driver
> updates.
>
> Check the System Log in Event Viewer for additional error messages
> that might help identify the device or driver that is causing bug
> check 0x133.
>
> Confirm that any new hardware that is installed is compatible with the
> installed version of Windows. For example, you can get information
> about required hardware at Windows 10 Specifications

[1]: [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x133-dpc-watchdog-violation#:~:text=The%20DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION%20bug%20check%20has,IRQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x133-dpc-watchdog-violation#:%7E:text=The%20DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION%20bug%20check%20has,IRQL))%20of%20DISPATCH_LEVEL%20or%20above.

Comment: About the BIOS, unfortunately :( I have the latest version of BIOS, also I am updating my drivers periodically(I'm a "latest software version" freak)

Comment: Please look in the System Log of Event Viewer (Admin Tools) and see if that provides a clue to the error.